# Two very close regexes with lookahead assertions in Python - why does re.split() behave differently?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I was trying to anser [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6709067) where the OP has the following string:

```
"path:bte00250 Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism path:bte00330 Arginine and proline metabolism"
```

and wants to split it to obtain the following list:

```
['path:bte00250 Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism', 'path:bte00330 Arginine and proline metabolism']
```

I tried to solve it by using a simple lookahead assertion in a regex, `(?=path:)`. Well, it did not work:

```
>>> s = "path:bte00250 Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism path:bte00330 Arginine and proline metabolism"
>>> r = re.compile('(?=path:)')
>>> r.split(s)
['path:bte00250 Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism path:bte00330 Arginine and proline metabolism']
```

However, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709067/python-regex-splitting-string-before-word/6709656#6709656), the answerer got it working by preceding the lookahead assertion with a whitespace:

```
>>> line = 'path:bte00250 Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism path:bte00330 Arginine and proline metabolism'
>>> re.split(' (?=path:)', line)
['path:bte00250 Alanine, aspartate and glutamate metabolism', 'path:bte00330 Arginine and proline metabolism']
```

Why did the regex work with the whitespace? Why did it not work without the whitespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's `re.split()` has a [documented limitation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split): It can't split on zero-length matches. Therefore the split only worked with the added space.