# string to list conversion in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like :

```
searchString = "u:sads asdas asdsad n:sadasda as:adds sdasd dasd a:sed eee"
```

what I want is list :

```
["u:sads asdas asdsad","n:sadasda","as:adds sdasd dasd","a:sed eee"]
```

What I have done is :

```
values = re.split('\s', searchString)
mylist = []
word = ''
for elem in values:
  if ':' in elem:
    if word:
      mylist.append(word)
    word = elem
  else:
    word = word + ' ' + elem
list.append(word)
return mylist
```

But I want an optimized code in **python 2.6** .

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - regex - Splitting string before word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709067/python-regex-splitting-string-before-word)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
mylist= re.split('\s+(?=\w+:)', searchString)
```

This splits the string everywhere there's a space followed by one or more letters and a colon. The look-ahead (`(?=` part) makes it split on the whitespace while keeping the `\w+:` parts

Answer (score 1):

You can use "look ahead" feature offered by a lot of regular expression engines. Basically, the regex engines checks for a pattern without consuming it when it comes to look ahead.

```
import re
s = "u:sads asdas asdsad n:sadasda as:adds sdasd dasd a:sed eee"
re.split(r'\s(?=[a-z]:)', s)
```

This means, split only when we have a `\s` followed by any letter and a colon but *don't* consume those tokens.